# Understanding the "lifespan" of context

Tags: go

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the "lifespan" of context.

I'm receiving RPC requests, and storing the request ID using `context.WithValue` so that it can be used for logging. There is no deadline or timeout for context in my service.

One of the methods called by RPC pulls some data from the database, calls a goroutine to do some processing (not relevant to the client), sends a response, and the method returns. The goroutine could run for ~15 seconds after the method returns.

I log the request ID in the goroutine a few times, and so far it works fine, but is there a situation where context could be garbage collected, and unavailable when I try to use it? Or will go know to keep context around until my goroutine has completed?

This leads me to another question - I'm not using `context.WithCancel`, does this mean it will remain in memory indefinitely? I'd imagine after a while this could cause some performance issues.

Comment: `is there a situation where context could be garbage collected, and unavailable when I try to use it?` if your code can reach it, then the GC will not garbage it. A context is like any other variable, nothing really special. `I'm not using context.WithCancel, does this mean it will remain in memory indefinitely?` no it just mean your context will never cancel.

Comment: Thanks so much @mh-cbon - that clears it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

A context is a glorified done channel. Depending on where the context comes from, determines how it should be reclaimed:

If you create a context (`context.WithCancel` etc.) ensure you reclaim it when the sub-task it represents completes (`defer cancelfn()` etc. ensure this happens on API return).

If you are using a context from an external source (e.g.a gRPC request) - it's the responsibility of the API framework to close out the context.

go will reclaim any memory during GC as long as there are no active references (function closures etc.)